# Issue with Samsung galaxy J1

Tags: samsung-mobile

I have an old galaxy J1 that would turn on and then go to a screen with some cogs that said 'optimizing android' but whenever it was just about to finish it would shut down.

I got a new battery for it and tried to force restart it but now it is stuck on screen that says 'Downloading' 'Do not turn off target' it has been like this for 4 days now. How can I fix it?